# How to check vlan interface traffic on Cisco nexus 9k

Tags: cisco, vlan, network, cisco-nexus

I have `Cisco N9K-C9396PX` L3 switch which has VLAN interface configured for my LAN gateway and i want to monitor how much traffic vlanXXX handling, I have configured SNMP monitoring to pull interface traffic but VLAN interface always empty and blank

```
N9K# show interface vlan 200
Vlan200 is up, line protocol is up, autostate disabled
  Hardware is EtherSVI, address is  58f3.9ca9.d769
  Description: *** LAN ***  Internet Address is 10.20.30.1/24
  MTU 9216 bytes, BW 1000000 Kbit, DLY 10 usec,
   reliability 255/255, txload 255/255, rxload 255/255
  Encapsulation ARPA, loopback not set
  Keepalive not supported
  ARP type: ARPA
  Last clearing of "show interface" counters never
  L3 in Switched:
    ucast: 0 pkts, 0 bytes
```

I heard you can use `counter` command on interface but i found that command doesn't exist anymore on N9K

Comment: One problem with your idea is that traffic only passes through the layer-3 interface as it is entering or leaving the VLAN. Traffic that is sourced and destined on the same VLAN does not pass through the layer-3 interface, only from the source layer-2 interface to the destination layer-2 interface. Remember that layer-2 switching is done in hardware, and unicast frames are sent directly from interface-to-interface by the MAC address table. Only unknown unicast, broadcast, and [possibly] multicast frames would hit other interfaces.

Comment: Have you thought about Netflow?
See "Configuring Bridged NetFlow on a VLAN:
[link](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/nexus9000/sw/7-x/system_management/configuration/guide/b_Cisco_Nexus_9000_Series_NX-OS_System_Management_Configuration_Guide_7x/b_Cisco_Nexus_9000_Series_NX-OS_System_Management_Configuration_Guide_7x_chapter_011100.html)

Comment: `show interface vlan 200 counters` works with .9.3.1 on a n3k

Comment: I ran that command but its has all counters are `zero` in output.